# SSD, HDD And Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, ssd

I've ordered an SSD (Cosair Force LX 128GB)
I have a HDD (Seagate Barricuda 320GB 72RPM)

Im still building my Custom pc. i have to get a mobo, ram, cpu, and psu. so im still using my old Dell inspiron 537(s).

I was wondering if i can install ubuntu, gnome shell and google chrome and maybe some other programs on the SSD but put my home folder and games on my HDD.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, that's possible as Ossian Mapes describes in the answer below. You can also use the SSD as a cache for the harddisk so that everything's installed on the HDD, but fast because of the SSD. There are several solutions for that, such as bcache, which you can read about here, if you're interested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcache

Comment: If not also installing Windows use gpt partitioning. New system will be UEFI and you then can with Ubuntu boot in either UEFI or CSM/BIOS boot modes if gpt. If MBR(msdos) you can only boot in BIOS mode. http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 AND: http://askubuntu.com/questions/446968/legacy-vs-uefi-help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Home on a different partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29689/home-on-a-different-partition)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a separate home partition, set the mountpoint off the HDD as **/home** when you format it in the Ubuntu Setup.