# Dual Boot Ubuntu on win 10 PC

Tags: windows, syslinux

I want to install ubuntu on PC already running windows 10. I downloaded linux and made a bootable USB drive but on startup the system directly boots win 10.

Also i dont get option for selecting my boot device.

What is the way forward ?

Comment: What is your laptop? Can you get into bios settings? And why 12.04?

Comment: The way forward is to make sure the computer boots from the USB drive.

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI have you turned on or allowed boot from USB devices in UEFI? Is download valid and bootable?

Comment: @Pilot6 - I have ASUS X series..i entered my Bios settings and i am not using 12.04 i am using 14.04

Comment: @oldfred What is the difference between BIOS and UEFI ?? I am using win 10 and i think it has UEFI

Comment: Your hardware is either BIOS or UEFI. And UEFI has a CSM mode which also is BIOS. All new systems with Windows 8 pre-installed are UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/446968/legacy-vs-uefi-help

Comment: Hello people...problem solved..I messed up with the BIOS settings earlier..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a new Asus laptop.
It came with win 8.1 which I immediately upgraded to Windows 10.
The usual method of getting in to BIOS no longer works. The <kbd>F2</kbd> key is ignored during boot.

After some investigation I discovered that by telling Windows 10 you are in a rescue situation. It will fix it so you can get into the BIOS for one boot only.  However, when you get into the BIOS you find that the boot options have been restricted. So that you can only select a partition on the main drive (in this case an SDD).

So Windows 10 does allow you to boot from the rescue partition but not from USB drive.